# How to change the row color of primefaces datatable while hover the row

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I need to change the default gray color of primefaces datatable row color while hover the row 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocmid.png)

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to customize the primefaces datatable by customizing the following classes

```
    .ui-datatable table{
        border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-header,.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-footer{
        text-align:center;padding:4px 10px;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-header{
        border-bottom:0px none;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-footer{
        border-top:0px none;
    }
    .ui-datatable thead th, .ui-datatable tfoot td{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .ui-datatable thead th,.ui-datatable tbody td,.ui-datatable tfoot td{
        padding:4px 10px;
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space:nowrap;
        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
    }
    .ui-datatable tbody td{
        border-color:inherit;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-sortable-column{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .ui-datatable div.ui-dt-c{
        position:relative;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-sortable-column-icon{
        display:inline-block;
        margin:-3px 0px -3px 2px;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-column-filter{
        display:block;
        width:100px;
        margin:auto;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-expanded-row{
        border-bottom:0px none;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-expanded-row-content{
        border-top:0px none;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-row-toggler{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .ui-datatable tr.ui-state-highlight{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-selection-column .ui-chkbox-all{
        display:block;
        margin:0px auto;
        width:16px;
        height:16px;
    }
    .ui-datatable-scrollable table{
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
    .ui-datatable-scrollable-body{
        overflow:auto;
    }
    .ui-datatable-scrollable-header,.ui-datatable-scrollable-footer{
        overflow:hidden;
        border:0px none;
    }
    .ui-datatable-scrollable .ui-datatable-scrollable-header,.ui-datatable-scrollable .ui-datatable-scrollable-footer{
        position:relative;
    }
     .ui-datatable-scrollable .ui-datatable-scrollable-header td{
        font-weight:normal;
    }
    .ui-datatable-scrollable-body::-webkit-scrollbar{
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        width:15px;
        background-color:transparent;
    }
    .ui-datatable-scrollable-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
        border-radius:8px;
        border:1px solid white;
        background-color:rgba(194,194,194,.5);
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data tr.ui-state-hover{
        border-color:inherit;
        font-weight:inherit;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-paginator,.ui-datatable .ui-paginator{
        padding:2px;
    }
    .ui-column-dnd-top, ui-column-dnd-bottom{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
    }
    .ui-column-dnd-top .ui-icon, ui-column-dnd-bottom .ui-icon{
        position:absolute;
        top:-4px;
    }
    /* InCell Editing */.ui-datatable .ui-cell-editor-input{
        display:none;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-row-editing .ui-cell-editor .ui-cell-editor-output{
        display:none;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-row-editing .ui-cell-editor .ui-cell-editor-input{
        display:block;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-row-editor span{
        cursor:pointer;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-row-editing .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil{
        display:none;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-check,.ui-datatable .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-close{
        display:none;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-row-editing .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-check,.ui-datatable .ui-row-editing .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-close{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data tr.ui-row-editing td.ui-editable-column,.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data td.ui-cell-editing{
        padding:0;margin:0;
    }
    /*resizer */.ui-datatable .ui-column-resizer{
        width:8px;height:20px;
        padding:0px;cursor:col-resize;
        background-image:url("/ScraperOnWeb/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif.jsf?ln=primefaces");
        margin:-4px -10px -4px 0px;
        float:right;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-filter-column .ui-column-resizer{
        height:45px;
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-column-resizer-helper{
        width:1px;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:10;
        display:none;
    }
    .ui-datatable-resizable{
        padding-bottom:1px;/*fix for webkit overlow*/overflow:auto;
    }
    .ui-datatable-resizable table{
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
    .ui-datatable-rtl{
        direction:rtl;
    }
    .ui-datatable-rtl.ui-datatable thead th, .ui-datatable-rtl.ui-datatable tfoot td{
        text-align:right;
    }
```

I hope it helps.
My problem was fixed by customizing the below classes

```
.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data tr.ui-state-hover.accept td {  
    color: black !important;
    background-color: #DCEDC8 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe you can reduce the css to the bare-minumum required for the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the hove class used by Primefaces is `.ui-state-hover`.
You will need a custom CSS file in which you will have to override the `.ui-state-hover` background color.

Comment: The below code is working fine .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data tr.ui-state-hover td{ 
 color: black !important;
 background-color: #f3f0f0 !important;
}